# i want to download a video from this URL

Tags: python, facebook, urllib

```python
import urllib
link = "https://www.facebook.com/cofidis/videos/1518507675176091/?__cft__[0]=AZWA0HX9K9N1U6ZGKugETU-gWHDvRPDv0Vg7kmZwd2cR45pt9_Uml9gYz33wD3taI1aZc_w18hmTiUVd7VIXQxQTecK5v76B6r7gUdBxf4V1mAJgbV77A_NMi-07ywYyAQrUFVIT0if2gNQpFMS8Dq91o0w3xwALSDf0WV7_41Vw7EQUMYldqmaU6ZE29VkNXE4&__tn__=%2B%3FFH-R"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, "video.mp4")
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also that link goes to an HTML page containing a video. It is not a link to a video.

Comment: That is not the URL to a video file, but to an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib

link = "https://www.facebook.com/cofidis/videos/1518507675176091/?cft[0]=AZWA0HX9K9N1U6ZGKugETU-gWHDvRPDv0Vg7kmZwd2cR45pt9_Uml9gYz33wD3taI1aZc_w18hmTiUVd7VIXQxQTecK5v76B6r7gUdBxf4V1mAJgbV77A_NMi-07ywYyAQrUFVIT0if2gNQpFMS8Dq91o0w3xwALSDf0WV7_41Vw7EQUMYldqmaU6ZE29VkNXE4&tn=%2B%3FFH-R"

opener = urllib.FancyURLopener()

opener.retrieve(link,"testout.flv")
```

Comment: when i downloaded a video, but when i want to read this video i get a problem with VLC.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is the simplest technique to achieve your aim.**

> ```
> downloader = urllib.FancyURLopener()
> downloader.retrieve(link,"video.mp4")
> ```

*Or,*

> ```
> file_name = 'video.mp4' 
> urllib.retrieve(link, file_name)
> ```